# How to block editing a drupal node according to a taxonomy term value?

Tags: drupal, conditional-statements, taxonomy, editing

I want to prevent users of my drupal site from editing the current node when the status of the node is closed.

The node is "closed" when the field (taxonomy term) == closed

Is there a way to do this please?
I really don't help about this on the topic. Nothing with rule module.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use module_node_access hook to alter the user permissions. see: [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/8.8.x)

Comment: It's always best to copy the answer here instead of supplying a URL. This way, if the URL no longer works, the answer is still valid in the future.